# Javascript cooldown for a div-button

Tags: javascript, html

I am in need of a 'cooldown' function for a div button, like this:

```
<div class="btn" id="cooldown" onClick="getGold(1)">Get some gold</div>
```

What I want it to do is disable itself for five seconds after being pressed and then re-enable itself again. Can someone help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Are you familiar with `setTimeout`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using setTimeout and document.GetElementById('cooldown').disable = true; - but could not get it to work

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried and explain what didn't work?

Comment: On an unrelated note: Don't use divs as buttons. Use the correct HTML tags. Otherwise you are screwing up your accessibility and creating a bad user experience.